# "How to get real date time even user changes system date" in c# windows application

Tags: datetime, c#-2.0

I am using 
`MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString());`
to get date and time.
My problem is when I change system date it displays updated date not a real date.
what I need is real date and time not operating system's date and time.
please do help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I have problems understanding your goal, if you change the clock you are looking at, how do you imagine to "devine" the  real time? Are you thinking of some local-independent time like GMT?
What sources of time are available to you? What is your environment? Does it have several realtime clocks? Can you access time servers via the internet? Can you ask the user for the time-difference between system clock and real-time (e.g. to represent the involved time-zone)?

Comment: If there was a way for computers to magically be able to deliver the *real* current time to programs reliably, there wouldn't be entire protocols dedicated to the problems of clock synchronization.

Comment: @JenithSamuel why did you edit in the c#-2.0 tag instead of just the c# tag? It doesn't seem like anything in the question is specific to c# 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the current time from some server over the internet like this for example: https://timezonedb.com/api

Maybe it's possible to get the time from the real time clock component on the motherboard, but the user could also just remove the CMOS battery or set the time in BIOS.

When you first run your program, save the current time to somewhere (hidden) on the disk, update that file every 15 minutes or so, and if the time is changing significantly like more than 1 hour, compare it to the file.

Otherwise there's no possible way to control this.

Comment: thank you for suggestion but I am developing windows application and my client is not using internet connection. If you have any offline suggestions please do let me know.

Comment: I would lean far out the window and say without internet it is not possible.
You would never know the very excact time with the file method and generally you would never know about time changes. ( summer/winter time ) Also how would you know that the first time you run your programm the time is valid? What if even at the first start the time is already incorrect? How would you know that?

Either trust the system or have Internet is what it comes down to I guess.

If I'm wrong please prove me wrong :) Gladly learn new stuff.

Comment: @Nico I'd say you're correct, there's no 100% absolutely reliable way to check the time (even with internet access you could forward the request to another server) but you could rely on multiple mechanisms to make it harder to change the time.

Comment: thank you for getting back. Well.. for the first time... what I will do is... I will get the mac address of system and save it in db. Now for "date & time issue"... what I think is I will save "current date time" in db as time for first entry and then I will calculate the years and months and so on. I know it is tedious but I do not find any other way. if you find any other way please do comment :)